# Hive delete query issue as Vertex failed as one or more tasks failed. failedTasks:1

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

The delete query on hive works for short time range for minute or two but throws error for larger time range, such as more than 2 minutes. It works fine for the other table with the same number of data. Do you have any idea to resolve this than please let me know.

```html
Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1450869601881_108799_25_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1450869601881_108799_25_01_000007, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:138)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:324)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:176)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:163)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:269)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.run(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:163)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:337)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:258)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:328)
        ... 16 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:138)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:324)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:176)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:163)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:269)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.run(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:163)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:337)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:258)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:328)
        ... 16 more
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:138)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:324)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:176)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:163)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:269)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.run(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:163)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:337)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:258)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:328)
        ... 16 more
], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:138)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:324)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:176)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.call(TezTaskRunner.java:163)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:269)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.run(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:163)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":{"transactionid":0,"bucketid":-1,"rowid":65795}},"value":null}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:337)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:258)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:328)
        ... 16 more
]], Vertex failed as one or more tasks failed. failedTasks:1, Vertex vertex_1450869601881_108799_25_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:null]
DAG failed due to vertex failure. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
```

Comment: could you provide some details at least on what type of error is thrown? Any logs output?

Comment: I have updated the post with the error logs.

Comment: Which Hive version is this?

Comment: I think  problem is with memory have you tried increasing the container memory.Also can you please provide logs by running "yarn logs -applicationId <appid> >>log.out" which will help to understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: @SachinJanani I increased the container size but no impact. Also upon running the app_id for the query I ran is saying 'doesn't have any logs' and I tried running the logs url for the application id, it not showing up.

Comment: In case if you want to tune Yarn here is a good manual/presentation [here](http://www.slideshare.net/guignol95/yarn-optimization-real-life-use-case?qid=3e1be86a-08db-4de2-990d-c59ca0b366e5&v=qf1&b=&from_search=1). So just increasing container size might not help.

Comment: @SachinJanani it seems there is nothing to do with container. Because I tried playing with the size, setting higher and lower. On making lower, I get 'Container killed on request'. This table is partitioned and clustered and we have data of 4 million for entire range (45 minutes)  and I am trying to delete the data only for 15 minutes or less.

Comment: @madbitloman it seems there is nothing to do with container. Because I tried playing with the size, setting higher and lower. On making lower, I get 'Container killed on request'. This table is partitioned and clustered and we have data of 4 million for entire range (45 minutes)  and I am trying to delete the data only for 15 minutes or less.

Comment: @rawal have you provide "-owner" option while executing "yarn logs" command it will be easy to debug if you provide the logs of the query